# Use jquery to show only the current option selected in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jquery.

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bashing_title').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 1)
        $('#1').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 2)
        $('#2').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 3)
        $('#3').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 4)
        $('#4').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 5)
        $('#5').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 6)
        $('#6').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 7)
        $('#7').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 8)
        $('#8').show();
        else if($(this).val() == 9)
        $('#9').show();

        else
        $('#1').hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

What I am trying to do is if the value is `1` it shows a specific text box, if its 2 then another one and so on. But here if the user has selected the option with value `1` at first and if the user selects `2` later, the one doesnt gets hidden.

how do i hide the previous value and only show the value that is curretly selection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give all of your inputs a class, and you can shorten the code to the following (Example class name is: `selectInput`

```
$('#bashing_title').change(function(){
    $(".selectInput").hide();
    $("#"+this.value).show();
});
```

HTML for the inputs (follow this style)

```
<input type="text" id="1" class="selectInput"/>
```

Comment: make sure you validate the answer :) if you found it satifiying.

Comment: Could you show me how to write jquery when i have differen ids such as `'Pick a reason'` or '`Title 1 or`  `'Title 2'` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work for you .

```
$('#bashing_title').change(function(){
    var selectvalue = $('#bashing_title').find(":selected").val();
    $('#'+selectvalue).show();
    });
```

Comment: Careful, the text from the selected option can be different from the actual value.

Comment: This isn't a very clean way to get the value, and you don't hide the previous selection, which is the real problem.

Comment: ohh i see , so this makes my answer useless ^^ glad you found the right one .